# (verification) Different Types of islower() METHOD in Python

Tags: python, string

Below I had elapsed 5 different functions made with islower().
The goal is to check whether the given function meets the purpose, which is to check whether the given string contains at least one lower case.
I had attached reason also, please check whether my analysis/explanation is valid.

```
#Example1: True
def any_lowercase1(s):
     for c in s:
          if c.islower():
               return True
          else:
               return False

#Example2: False
## this function checks only the string 'c' is lower, which always returns True
def any_lowercase2(s):
     for c in s:
          if 'c'.islower():
               return 'True'
          else:
               return 'False'

#Example3: False
##the result only depends on the last letter of given string

def any_lowercase3(s):
     for c in s:
          flag = c.islower()
     return flag

#Example4: False
##Similar to Example3, this function also depends on the last character of given string
def any_lowercase4(s):
     flag = False
     for c in s:
          flag = flag or c.islower()
     return c.islower()


#Example5: False
## This function returns False if it conatains more than one Captial Letter.
def any_lowercase5(s):
     for c in s:
          if not c.islower():
               return False
     return True

print(any_lowercase4('RrR'))
#above must be true, but it returns False
```

Comment: You're mostly right except a few things: The first one will only test the first char of s (it always returns during the first pass through the loop). The fourth one actually works fine, because it remembers whether it's seen a lowercase letter before. Once the flag is set True, it will stay True till the end. The fifth one will return False if there's even a single capital letter (it will return as soon as it finds the first one).

Comment: By the way, this is a simple way to do this test: `any(c.islower() for c in s)`.

Comment: @MatthiasFripp Matthia, would you tell me why the first one always check only the first letter even it has a for loop?

Comment: The first time through the loop, c will hold the first letter of s. If c is lowercase, the function will return True. Otherwise (if c is a capital) it will return False. There's no way to get past the if/else statement without returning, so there's no way to continue the loop to the next letter.

Comment: @MatthiasFripp Got it. Following your guidance, one must be careful not to insert return predicates inside of loop

Comment: More like you should be careful how you use them - sometimes they can be useful. For example, example 5 would do exactly what you want if you swapped False and True and dropped the `not`. That would be a common and effective use of `return` within a loop. (As written, example 5 is a very good way to find out if there are any capital letters in the string.)

Answer (score 0):

I would use regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('[a-z]', 'RrR')
['r']
>>> re.findall('[a-z]', 'RRR')
[]
```

Example4 doesn't work, because you return `c.islower()`, when you should return `flag`.

## EDIT

If you need to check which function works, which not -- write some tests with know data:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ONLY_LOWER = ['aaa', 'a', 'hello', 'foo and bar']
    NOT_LOWER = ['X', 'Xa', 'Aha', 'Try this One']
    FUNCS = [any_lowercase1, any_lowercase2, any_lowercase3, any_lowercase4, any_lowercase5]


    good_funcs = [f.__name__ for f in FUNCS]
    for f in FUNCS:
        result = True
        for item in ONLY_LOWER:
            if not f(item):
                print("Function '<{}>' returned false for lower item '{}'".format(f.__name__, item))
                if f.__name__ in good_funcs:
                    good_funcs.remove(f.__name__)
                break
        for item in NOT_LOWER:
            if f(item):
                print("Function '<{}>' returned true for non lower item '{}'".format(f.__name__, item))
                if f.__name__ in good_funcs:
                    good_funcs.remove(f.__name__)
                break

    print("Here are function, which passed the tests: {}".format(good_funcs))

>> Function '<any_lowercase2>' returned true for non lower item 'X'
>> Function '<any_lowercase3>' returned true for non lower item 'Xa'
>> Function '<any_lowercase4>' returned true for non lower item 'Xa'
>> Function '<any_lowercase5>' returned false for lower item 'foo and bar'
>> Here are function, which passed the tests: ['any_lowercase1']
```

Comment: above example is intentionally errored for practice to check why the function wrong.

Comment: Then what you are asking for?

Comment: Among above 5 functuons, only first one checks whether the given string contains any lower casw. Is it true?